# can somebody help me figure out what is the problem in my code?

Tags: python, string

```
string = input()

for i in string:
    if 'h' in string:
        if 'e' in string+'h':
            if 'll' in string+'h'+'e':
                if 'o' in string+'h'+'e'+'ll':
                    status = True
    else:
        status = False
        
if status:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'status' is not defined

May anyone please help me figure out what is the problem in my code??

Comment: What is it supposed to do? `'e' in string+'h'` will be true if and only if `'e' in string`. What's the point of all this?

Comment: Please read tags description before adding them. DSA is for Digital Signature Algorithm only. Please also read this: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what the other answer pointed out, a few observations:

`if 'e' in string+'h':`

The `+'h'` part is pointless - it can't possibly make any difference, given that `h` does not equal `e`.

Also, the `for` loop is pointless because you never do anything with `i` - you just do the same comparison repeatedly.

You could just write this whole thing as:

```
if 'h' in string and 'e' in string and 'll' in string and 'o' in string:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define status variable:

```
string = input()

status = False

for i in string:
    if 'h' in string:
        if 'e' in string+'h':
            if 'll' in string+'h'+'e':
                if 'o' in string+'h'+'e'+'ll':
                    status = True
        
if status:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Although, I am not sure I have got logic of your code

Comment: Yes that was right . thanks for help

Comment: Please check your code logic as for cycle seem to me redundant
it looks like it can be reduced to 
status = 'h' in string and 'e' in string and 'll' in string and 'o' in string